# plotting data with thousands of points and its label(group) with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have an array of 500000 samples i.e., the data's shape is `(500000, 3)` where the first two columns represent x-coordinate and y- coordinate, and the third column is Label values to which the datapoint @ (X,Y) belongs.

for example:- `data= [ [20,10, 12.3320], [22, 13, 230.221],.....[..] ]`

I tried the below method. But this is too time consuming and poorly interpreted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = 10*['r.','g.','b.','c.','k.','y.','m.']

for i in range(len(labels)):
    plt.scatter(data[i][0], data[i][1], colors[labels[i]],marker='.')

plt.show()
```

Is there any other method like `imshow()` or other which is suitable for the above code which leads  to good interpretation?

Comment: In order to use `imshow` the data must be equally spaced on a grid. Is this the case? Can you tell us more how your data is structured in the columns?

Comment: The data structure is like this                                                                   array([[ 0.19975574,  0.10402092,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.10727158,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.11052223,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.11377289,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.11702354,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.12027419,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.12352485,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.1267755 ,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.13002616,  0.00029645],
       [ 0.19975574,  0.13327681,  0.00029645],...........])

Comment: the data is scaled to have unit variance in each axis.. So the data looks above.

Comment: don't put your data into the comments. Also you can answer questions from the comment section simply by editing your question. Showing the original data makes things a bit complicated. To see the structure, use some other data, in the sense of a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

The scatter function in matlplotlib is quiet slow, I would recommend to use vispy that use the GPU to plot a large number of points :

Works with vispy 0.4.0 that you can install with pip or conda :

```
pip install vispy
```

Here is the code (plotted in less than 2sec on my computer):

```
import numpy as np
from vispy import scene, visuals, app
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((500000,3))

canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', show=True)
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
# Create the scatter plot
scatter = scene.visuals.Markers()
scatter.set_data(data[:,:2], face_color=plt.cm.jet(data[:,2]))
view.add(scatter)
view.camera = scene.PanZoomCamera(aspect=1)
view.camera.set_range()
app.run()
```

there is a nice documentation for vispy and you can customize your plot in the `set_data` function with arguments like **face_color, edge_color, size, edge_width, symbol ...**

Good luck with your data visualization ;)

Comment: Note if you get a black screen with no markers, there's an issue in vispy: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/issues/1085

Comment: Hi there, I run this code on ipython notebook and I received nothing. Do you know what is the issue?

Comment: Try to launch it as a python script and not as a ipython notebook :)